# android compose textfield how to dismiss keyboard on touch outside

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Here is a Row that contains a TextField in a full-screen column. `onFocusChanged` callback is called when tapping the TextField (going Active) and when the Done button is pressed in the keyboard. But the handler is not called I tap outside the TextField. So I am not able to close the keyboard. Any idea?

```kotlin
val (nameText, setNameText) = remember { mutableStateOf("")}
val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
val focusRequester = FocusRequester()

Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .fillMaxHeight()
        .padding(10.dp)
) { 
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround
    ) {
        TextField(
            value = nameText,
            onValueChange = setNameText,
            modifier = Modifier
                .focusRequester(focusRequester)
                .onFocusChanged {
                    if (!it.isFocused) {
                        keyboardController?.hide()
                    }
                }
                .padding(horizontal = 0.dp, vertical = 0.dp)
                .height(50.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            KeyboardOptions(
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
                imeAction = androidx.compose.ui.text.input.ImeAction.Done
            ),
            keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onDone = {
                localFocusManager.clearFocus()
            }),
            placeholder = { Text("Enter a name", fontSize = 14.sp) }
        )
    }
}
```

I tried setting a focus handler in Column but did not work (focus handler not called when tapping outside). Using compose version 1.0.2.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you want to remove focus on tap, you can add `pointerInput` modifier with `detectTapGestures` to your `Column`:

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .fillMaxHeight()
        .padding(10.dp)
        .pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectTapGestures(onTap = {
                localFocusManager.clearFocus()
            })
        }
)
```

I add it after the `padding` modifier, so the padding view part won't receive touches. If you change the order, padding will be included in the clickable part.

Look at [other gestures](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/gestures) if tap is not enough for you.

Comment: Thanks! This solution works perfecly fine on screens but fails somehow on Bottomsheet composables. Trying to figure the working solution, will update once resolved fully!

Comment: @sud007 you can create a separate question and post your answer there - then you can leave a link to that answer in comment here